# Property or indexer cannot be assigned to “” it is read only

Tags: c#, datagridview, properties

In the same form of my ultimate question I cant set a `dataGridView` property

```
private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font.Size = 4;
}
```

I have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 1):

The error-message is self-explanatory. Yo can't set a value to the `Font` property. Try this instead:

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 11F, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Comment: thanks, and how i read it?